# Air handling system (AHU) design in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica, hvac

I am trying to model simple AHU in a room using Buldings package. A room is linked to ambient air outside using orifice and supply fan and return fan are connected to the room and the mixing box (using Buildings library/Fluid/Actuators/Dampers/MixingBox. With the current setup I shows I have one extra variable compared to equations. I was just wondering if I have missed some major components in the design.[image: AHU Picture]